# Json decode and 'Inline Local Variable' is resulting in _TypeError

Tags: flutter, dart

I am parsing a JSON array to an `Iterable<Dto>` such as:

```dart
final Iterable l = json.decode(resp.body);
Iterable<Dto> dtos = l.map((data) => Dto.fromJson(data));
```

But it results in `_TypeError (type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<Dto>')` when we chain the two statements in:

```dart
Iterable<Dto> dtos = json
                       .decode(resp.body)
                       .map((data) => Dto.fromJson(data));
```

Notice, this is the result of the refactor operation `Inline Local Variable`.

So, how should we properly refactor with 'Inline Local Variable'?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below lines;

```dart
Iterable<Dto> dtos = (json.decode(resp.body) as Iterable)
                       .map((data) => Dto.fromJson(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also get them as List:

`var l = json.decode(resp.body);`

`List<Dto> dtos = l.map((data) => Dto.fromJson(data)).toList();`